# Create Recursive Form Elements

Tags: javascript, html, forms, recursion

I'm creating a homework calculator. I need to recursively create form elements, and found out how to make a recursively creating table. How do I turn the spaces in that table into form elements that create themselves recursively? If this isn't clear, please tell  me.

```html
<table id="xTable"></table>
<script>
var rQty = parseInt(prompt("Number of Rows"), 10);
var cQty = parseInt(prompt("Number of Columns"), 10);
var table = document.getElementById("xTable");

for (let i = 0; i < rQty; i++) {
    var row = table.insertRow();
    for (let j = 0; j < cQty; j++) {
        var cell = row.insertCell();
        cell.textContent = "I want to make this into a recursive form creator ";
    }
}
</script>
<style>
td {
    border: 2px ridge #333;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Hi! I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve – do you want to have some form elements (like `<input type="text">`) inside the cells of your table?

Comment: @David Yes, to put it in all cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's rather simple, just create the elements you want to insert into the cells with `document.createElement`, then set the properties you want them to have and use `cell.appendChild` to place them into the cell.

This example creates `<input type="text">` elements:

```js
var rQty = parseInt(prompt("Number of Rows"), 10);
var cQty = parseInt(prompt("Number of Columns"), 10);
var table = document.getElementById("xTable");

for (let i = 0; i < rQty; i++) {
    var row = table.insertRow();
    for (let j = 0; j < cQty; j++) {
        var cell = row.insertCell();
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = 'text';
        input.name = 'input_r' + i + '-c' + j;
        
        cell.appendChild(input);
    }
}
```

```css
td {
    border: 2px ridge #333;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table id="xTable"></table>
```